# Javascript :Replace URL content string with another url

Tags: javascript

Javascript :Replace URL content--I have following html file and I want to replace URL with a new URL but my problem is i dont know exact value of a0 ,it can be any URL,any help will be appreciated thanks

```
 <html>
   <body>
     <a href="http://www.google.com?query=domain">domain</a>
       <script>    
                           document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace('<ahref='.concat('\"http:*****************\"//','>domain</a>'),'domain');
```

document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace('domain','http://www.google.com?query=hello\"','domain>domain'));

```
       </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the anchors and swap (in a load event)?

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].href.toLowerCase() == a0) {
      links[i].href = a1;
    }
}
```